# Set a postman variable value from the Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, postman, gitlab-ci, postman-collection-runner, newman

There are two variables defined for my test. I want to set these values through the CI.

```
Below is the code from gitlab-ci.yml
smoketest-test:
  stage: smoketests-test
  dependencies:
  - deploy-test
  image: 
    name: postman/newman:alpine
    # entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - newman --version.sh
    - npm install -g newman-reporter-html
    - newman runs tests/postmanui-tests.json -e tests/${ENV_VAR}_environment.json "uname" = "abc"
  artifacts:
     when: always
     paths:
      - report.html
  only:
    - master
  except:
    - schedules
  tags:
    - environment_test
```

How can I pass the variable "uname" value from the CI? Currently it is not being passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual variables can be overridden with the `--env-var` flag.

To hardcode the values:

```
    - newman run tests/postmanui-tests.json -e tests/${ENV_VAR}_environment.json --env-var uname="abc"
```

To use Gitlab CI variables:

```
variables:
  uname: default-value
  abc: default-value

...

    - newman run tests/postmanui-tests.json -e tests/${ENV_VAR}_environment.json --env-var ${uname}=${abc}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.  One more question in the postman collection json file I have there are two folders like two items with a different set of tests in each folder. i want to run one folder at a time is there a way to tell in the command newman run tests/postmanui-tests.json like "newman run tests/postmanui-tests.json/foldername"

Comment: Yes, that can be done with `newman run tests/postmanui-tests.json --folder <foldername>`